# How to get the number of tasks in a queue in executor service?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

So I am using executorservice to create a threadpool.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

I am trying to access the number of tasks in the queue of the threadpool. I see that there are no methods to get that.
I know there are methods to get the queue size in threadpoolexecutor but how can I do that with executorservice object.

Like I said I can get the queue information if I have created a ThreadpoolExecutor like this

```
ThreadPoolExecutor tpExecutor =  new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

I know I can use the tpExecutor.queue.size() to get the number of tasks in queue of threadpool. 
But currently I have declared my threadpool using Executor Service. How can I do that?
It would be appreciable if people can write code and demonstrate.

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` where `nThreads =1`?

Comment: What will I get from that? How can I get the number of tasks in queue of threadpool? Please be elaborate.

Comment: Assuming that `newSingleThreadExecutor()` is actually returning a type of `ThreadPoolExector`, you can just cast the object and call https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount--  Not sure why that's important though.

Comment: @markspace Your assumption is wrong, look at my comment below.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) this.executorService;
    int activeCount = threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount();
    long taskCount = threadPoolExecutor.getTaskCount();
    long completedTaskCount = threadPoolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount();
    long tasksToDo = taskCount - completedTaskCount - activeCount;
```

For some reason though it does not always exclude all the cancelled tasks, only after some periodic clean ups. So I had to introduce a second counter:

```
    long tasksToDo2 = threadPoolExecutor.getQueue().stream().filter(t -> !((FutureTask) t).isDone()).count();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cast this to ThreadPoolExecutor.

ThreadPoolExecutor ex=(ThreadPoolExecutor)executor;
ex.getQueue().size();

Comment: It doesn't work as Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() returns a delegated executor service that exposes only the ExecutorService methods. I use Java 1.8. I advise you to look at the source code: http://www.fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/Executors-source.html If you really want to get the thread pool executor, you'll have to use the reflection API, I've found no smart solution to do that.

Comment: Inside an application server like Glassfish, a managed executor service implements ExecutorService interface but there is no assuption about what class is used.

Comment: @gouessej This solution will work if you create an executor service using `newFixedThreadPool()`. If you only need a single thread, why not call `newFixedThreadPool(1)` instead of `newSingleThreadExecutor()`?